# Trouble shooting IIS Hostable Web Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to run the IIS Hostable Web Core sample at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2008/04/14/host-your-own-web-server-in-your-application-using-iis-7-0-hostable-web-core/

When I run it, without change, I can successfully return static html pages (using the ASP.Net configuration), but nothing happens with .aspx pages (the .aspx page is just the html page renamed to .aspx).  It is just a zero length page (no complaints from IE).

How do I go about trouble shooting this?  Are there standard log files?  The HWC api looks very simple; I'm guessing I need to be looking into IIS logging/trouble shooting?  All the IIS troubleshooting I've found online uses the IIS set up tools, which wont work as HWC is configured through .config files.

Comment: I'm trying to follow that blog post too. However, where is the `WebServer` class coming from? Do you remember by chance?

Comment: No, that was a long time ago, and I don't have access to the source I wrote anymore (changed jobs).  I have code that is 2 years old that doesn't work with the latest .net libraries.  It may be the sample is out of date.  Maybe try an older version of the .net.  Or maybe you just need to reference the right assembly - I don't know an easy way of find it, other than try an reference all dlls in the IIS binary directory.

Comment: I see, thank you for your quick reply. I have a hunch that it's not actually a .NET Framework class but something the author has written to interact with the native hwebcore.dll library.

Answer (score 1):

Eureka!  I can't shed much more light on how to troubleshoot, but I've worked around the problem by changing the .Net build setting "Platform Target" from "Any CPU" to x86.

Thanks, Amit